# how to push from Pycharm to Github files that I copy/paste on the project?

Tags: python, pycharm

**Step 1:**
I create a Pycharm project and I create a Github repository from it.

OR

I create a Github repository and I pull it to create a Pycharm project.

.

**Step 2:**
I copy/paste files that I want to use from another project into my new PyCharm project.

Theses files are available from PyCharm but when I commit and push the project, they aren't push to Github.

PS: if I create theses files from the PyCharm interface and copy/paste the code on the file, it works like a charm.

.

**Question:** How to add theses "manually added files" to the Github repository ?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving

Comment: It wasn't an error, I just didn't knew where to find it, the time I wrote the question, I found the solution. Sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file -> Git -> Add

`Ctrl+Alt+A`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Commit panel that can trigger by `Alt + 0` where you can click to add files, write commit message, and push from the panel there.

[image: Commit panel in PyCharm]

To Push, or Pull, you can use the shortcut here at the top left of screen. Or use `Ctrl + Shift + K` for a shortcut to push.

[image: Push button]